# Pretty Faces: Generic URL mapping

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, prettyfaces

Using Pretty Faces 3, I have some mappings like these:

```
<url-mapping id="search"> 
    <pattern value="/search" /> 
    <view-id value="/views/search.xhtml" />
</url-mapping> 

<url-mapping id="edit"> 
    <pattern value="/edit" /> 
    <view-id value="/views/edit.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Is there any way to define all them using some wildcard, like this?

```
<url-mapping id="generic"> 
    <pattern value="/*" /> 
    <view-id value="/views/$1.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

I know is possible to use EL in the view-id value, but I can manage it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its currently not possible to use a wildcard like this.

However as you already mentioned you could use a dynaview (EL expression for the view-id) to achieve something similar. We recently [fixed a bug](http://code.google.com/p/prettyfaces/issues/detail?id=120) that prevented something like this to work correcty. Perhaps you could give [3.3.1-SNAPSHOT a try](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/wiki/Snapshots). My guess is that it will work fine now. Feel free to post a message on the [forums](http://ocpsoft.com/support/forum/prettyfaces-users) if you have any further problems.

Comment: can you please tell me what's the right syntax for solving that case?

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://ocpsoft.org/support/topic/injection-time#post-1669

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using [Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/) which lets you do more powerful configuration:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/socialpm/blob/master/web/src/main/java/com/ocpsoft/socialpm/URLRewriteConfiguration.java

```
 .addRule(Join.path("/{page}").to("/views/{page}.xhtml"))
```