# Using PrettyFaces 3.3.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

i downloaded the 3.3.1-SNAPSHOT version to make generic url
regarding this post:

[Pretty Faces: Generic URL mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026232/pretty-faces-generic-url-mapping)

my configuration is as follows:

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd&quot; id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>myapp</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationSecurity.xml
        </param-value>

  </context-param>

  <!-- Activating the Expression Language -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>users</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

my pretty-config.xml:

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0
               http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.0.xsd"&gt;

    <url-mapping id="generic">
    <pattern value="/*" />
    <view-id value="/faces/$1.xhtml" />
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

the following line keeps repeating in terminal:

`at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.annotation.WebClassesFinder.processDirectory(WebClassesFinder.java:183)
at`

Comment: You forgot to include the exception type/message in the question. Posting only one line of the stacktrace isn't helpful.

Comment: @BalusC this is the weird thing, the console is full with this line only, when i go to application log file, couldn't find the exception, advise ?

Comment: It apparently ran into an infinite loop. I'd report it as a bug to PrettyFaces guys.

Comment: @BalusC , i already reported to them, so can you you suggest any other library like prettyFaces to make generic url mapping as i was trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mika,

This is not something that PrettyFaces supports using the URL-mapping construct, you must instead use a custom rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite match="/(.*)" substitute="/faces/$1.xhtml" />
```

However, consider the impact of such a rule (similar to the one you defined above.) Of course there will be an infinite loop, because "*" also matches "/faces/XXX.xhtml". You need to make your match pattern more restrictive.

```
<rewrite match="^/(.*)(?<!\.xhtml)$" substitute="/faces/$1.xhtml" />
```

I also suggest you read up on Regular expressions, because "/*" is not a regular expression that will do what you seem to think it will do: http://ocpsoft.com/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-2/#lookaround

However, if you want a URL-rewriting tool which was designed specifically to perform tasks like this, then I suggest you look at OCPsoft Rewrite: http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/, a much more powerful (but more difficult to use) URL-rewriting tool.

It allows you to do things like this:

```
       .addRule(Join.path("/{page}")
                .to("/pages/{page}.xhtml")
                .when(Resource.exists("/pages/{page}.xhtml"))
                .where("page").matches("(?!RES_NOT_FOUND)[^/]+"))
```